# Router Reuse Strategy breaking router

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to persist component data when user close/refresh tab or (click back/forth) using Router Reuse Strategy, but after adding CustomReuseStrategy provider routerLink stopped working properly.

After login we are redirected to '/dashboard/begin', then if i try to go '/dashboard/search' or '/dashboard/123' via routerLink the component doesn't change

However, a direct access url works well

Has anyone ever experienced this?

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    {
      provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
      useClass: CustomReuseStrategy
    }]
})
```

app.routing.ts

```
 const ROUTES: Routes = [
      { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule', canActivateChild: [AuthGuard]},
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
]
```

dashboard.routing.ts

```
const DASHBOARD_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'begin',
        component: BeginListComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'search',
        children: [
          {path: '', component: SearchListComponent },
          {path: ':id', component: SearchIdComponent}
        ]
      }
   }
 ]
```

custom.reuse.strategy.ts

```js
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, DetachedRouteHandle, RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  public static handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};

  private static waitDelete: string;

  public static deleteRouteSnapshots(): void {
    CustomReuseStrategy.handlers = {};
  }

  public static deleteRouteSnapshot(name: string): void {
    if (CustomReuseStrategy.handlers[name]) {
      delete CustomReuseStrategy.handlers[name];
    } else {
      CustomReuseStrategy.waitDelete = name;
    }
  }

  public shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    console.log(route);
    if (!route) {
      CustomReuseStrategy.deleteRouteSnapshots();
      return false;
    }
    if (route.params && Object.keys(route.params).length > 0) {
      return false; 
    }
    return true;
  }

  public store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    if (
      CustomReuseStrategy.waitDelete &&
      CustomReuseStrategy.waitDelete === this.getRouteUrl(route)
    ) {
      CustomReuseStrategy.waitDelete = null;
      return;
    }
    CustomReuseStrategy.handlers[this.getRouteUrl(route)] = handle;
  }

  public shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return !!CustomReuseStrategy.handlers[this.getRouteUrl(route)];
  }


  public retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
    if (!route.routeConfig) {
      return null;
    }

    return CustomReuseStrategy.handlers[this.getRouteUrl(route)];
  }

  public shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return (
      future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig &&
      JSON.stringify(future.params) === JSON.stringify(curr.params)
    );
  }

  private getRouteUrl(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return route['_routerState'].url.replace(/\//g, '_');
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find an anser for this ?

Comment: Could you clarify your initial premise?  You said "I'm trying to persist component data when user close/refresh tab or (click back/forth)".  Route Reuse Strategy is not a solution to remembering the page when the user closes the browser tab (except with very different code than yours using e.g. local storage).  I'm guessing what I understood is not what you meant.  Anyway, did setting breakpoints in the CustomReuseStrategy methods help at all in figuring out why routerLinks were not working?